# Default preset of headers in Postman

Tags: rest, postman

When manually testing requests in Postman, is there a way to define some set of default headers to be used for each request (without choosing manually Preset before sending each request)?
I.e. is there a way to define a default Preset to be used?

Additionaly when I follow some of the links in the response (by clicking on it) and send a request for this link, the headers from the original request are lost. Is there a way to preserve them automatically?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6):

There is no direct way to do this but this can be done via Collection level Pre-request script. Steps-

1. Create a collection in the postman and put all requests in which you want the common headers.
2. Edit the postman collection.

[image]

3. Write this in your Pre-request Script section.

```html
var Header = require('postman-collection').Header;
pm.request.headers.add(new Header("foo:foo"))
pm.request.headers.add(new Header("bar:bar"))
```

Comment: You can also do this... `pm.request.headers.add({key: "foo", value: "bar"})` - without the need of the `require` statement. 

Answer (score 5):

**As of 7.0.9** - You should be able to now do this in your Pre-request Scripts.

You can use the following syntax:

```
pm.request.headers.add({key: 'header_name', value: 'header_value' })

pm.request.headers.upsert({key: 'header_name', value: 'header_value' })

pm.request.headers.remove('header_name')
```

**Tips:** Fork this collection to see how it works directly in Postman:
https://www.postman.com/postman/workspace/postman-answers/collection/9215231-ef055751-7385-45b4-a6f9-91bbd1c47fa5?ctx=documentation

Comment: Excellent answer. Collections are not always used.